# How to convert an array to JSON string in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

How to convert an array to JSON string?

In my code I've fetch the data from query string in GET request method.

By using

```
 $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

I got all the values of query string and the data is in string format.

```
 start_date=2014-10-10&end_date=2014-12-12&limit=20&offset=5
```

But I need to convert it into json format

For that I exploded the string by taking '&' as delimiter.

Output is

```
(
    [0] => start_date=2014-10-10
    [1] => end_date=2014-12-12
    [2] => limit=20
    [3] => offset=5
)
```

How to convert this into json format

I need the data in the form of

```
(
    [start_date] => 2014-10-10
    [end_date] => 2014-12-12
    [limit] => 20
    [offset] => 5
)
```

please help me..

How to convert the string directly into json format?

and

How to convert the array into json format?

Comment: Do you actually want it as JSON?  Your final block of data looks more like an associative array, ie the contents of [`$_GET`?](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this:

```
//"start_date=2014-10-10&end_date=2014-12-12&limit=20&offset=5" sample value of $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] =

$str_params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
parse_str($str_params, $array_params);
$jsonParams = json_encode($array_params);
```

OUTPUT of parse_str will be stored in $array_params in array format:

```
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2014-10-10
    [end_date] => 2014-12-12
    [limit] => 20
    [offset] => 5
)
```

after json_encode, the value of $jsonParams should be:

```
{"start_date":"2014-10-10","end_date":"2014-12-12","limit":"20","offset":"5"}
```

Answer (score 0):

By splitting `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` by `&` you are not only on the wrong path but you also took the harder path instead of the shorter one.

You can use the function [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the query string as in:

```
$vars = array();
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $vars);
```

Even more, the query string is already parsed and the values you get in `$vars` already exist in `$_GET`. `print_r($_GET)` should produce exactly the data you are aiming for.

All in all, if you need `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` rewritten as `JSON` then the easiest way to do it is:

```
$asJson = json_encode($_GET);
```